# c - fix unknown register name ‘%xmm1’ in ‘asm’?

Tags: c, assembly

i am trying to build a project for ubuntu 14.04 X86 and I've got the following error:

```
error: unknown register name ‘%xmm1’ in ‘asm’
         asm volatile (
         ^
   error: unknown register name ‘%xmm0’ in ‘asm’
   error: unknown register name ‘%mm1’ in ‘asm’
   error: unknown register name ‘%mm0’ in ‘asm’
   error: unknown register name ‘%xmm0’ in ‘asm’
         asm volatile (
             ^
   error: unknown register name ‘%mm0’ in ‘asm’
          asm volatile (
```

in function :

```
static inline void
hev_bytes_xor_sse (guint8 *data, gsize size, guint8 byte)
{
    gsize i = 0, c = 0, p128 = 0, p64 = 0;
    guint64 w = (byte << 8) | byte;

    asm volatile (
        "movq %0, %%mm0\t\n"
        "pshufw $0x00, %%mm0, %%mm1\t\n"
        "movq2dq %%mm1, %%xmm0\t\n"
        "pshufd $0x00, %%xmm0, %%xmm1\t\n"
        ::"m"(w)
        :"%mm0", "%mm1", "%xmm0", "%xmm1"
    );
```

gcc version 4.8.2

Comment: It compiled fine for me under Fedora 17 (yeah, I should upgrade), gcc version 4.7.2. I didn't set any special compile flags. What exactly what your compile command line?

Comment: Tried compiling with `-mmmx -msse2`?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't actually using an i386 version of gcc.  Maybe a problem with your path?  What does gcc -v show for target?

Answer (score 1):

You can check what target-specific options `gcc` uses, using:
`gcc -Q --help=target`. `gcc -O3 -Q --help=target` does the same but for `-O3`.

In order to compile this code, you need to have `-mmmx` and `-msse2` enabled. If that's not the case, you can just pass them over the command line: `gcc -mmmx -msse2 ...`.